# grouping parsed data into "like" groups

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, loops

I currently have a script that parses a text file with (for example) 100 lines, from 10 different users, and for each line pulls out a `$userName`, `$timestamp` and a variety of other things. Is there a way that I can loop through (after it does the parsing) and work with 1 group of `$userName` at a time.

The end goal is to enter the data into google docs 1 user at a time.

I have tried using `$i` and `$i++` however due to the fact that my primary loop is an array within an array things get a little goofy.

What I would like is the ability to see the following

```
$userName   |   $timeStamp
mhopkins321 |    13-12-30
mhopkins321 |    14-59-01
mhopkins321 |    19-32-59
```

Comment: A question mark _?_ is used in English to determine a _question_. I am unable to spot the question mark ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to make the proper array structure:

```
$users = array(
    'mhopkins321' => array(
        '13-12-30',
        '14-59-01',
         ...
    ),
    'anotherUser' => array(
          ...
    )
);
```

So when you're parsing, and run into a username and timestamp:

```
$users[$username][] = $timestamp;
```

And when you want to make that table

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    foreach ($user as $timestamp) {
        echo $user."| ".$timestamp."\n";
    }
}
```

...probably with better formatting, but there ya go.